# How to build and run production NodeJS express server with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I have a server written in `express` nodejs framework. and currently it has a `app.js` as below:

```
// app.js

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
var cors = require('cors');

// routes
const books = require('./routes/api/books');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// cors
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world!'));

app.get('/health-check',(req,res)=> {
    res.send ("OK");
});

// use Routes
app.use('/api/books', books);

// const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

And I run the above server using the following command:

```
npm run app
```

How can I make this a production level build and run it?

Can I use below `Dockerfile` to do it?

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production env
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: You're missing a couple of things here. Your node/express is running on 8080 and you put the files in nginx (/usr/share/nginx/html) and expose them on port 80. 
You need to connect the two ports.

What I do is create a container with only the Node/Express App in it. And then a docker container (in docker-compose) publishing the port (8080) to something else (8090?). And I keep the Nginx on the Host machine and use nginx as a proxy (mapping 8090 to a subdomain).

Comment: So that means we can't build an `express` app just like we do for a `reatjs` app?

Comment: No, you can't. An React-App is (after the build) just a static website. (Unless ServerSideRendering like NextJS).
And an Express App is a dynamic NodeJS environment.